# platform-based branching in detox tests

Tags: detox

I have a test suite written in Detox and I am adding android support. In my tests some button which I don't have control over have different names between iOS and Android.

How can I have my test do a:
`await element(by.text('OK')).tap();` on iOS 
and
`await element(by.text('Done')).tap();`
on android?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `device.getPlatform()` .

https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#devicegetplatform

Example from Detox's test suite:
https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/detox/test/e2e/02.matchers.test.js#L18